# Comparing growth rate between $\log(x)$ and $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: functions

Is there an $n > 0$ such that $\mathcal{O}(x^{\frac{1}{n}}) < \mathcal{O}(\log(x))$? It seems like there isn't, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that n must be positive.

Comment: Side note: this is an abuse of Big-O notation. You mean $x^{1/n}=O(\log(n))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer this, one must compute (assuming $n>0$).

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{1/n}}.
$$

Using l'Hopital's rule, you get that this equals
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{x^{1/n-1}}{n}}=n\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1/n}}=0.
$$

Therefore, your original assessment is incorrect (for all $n$, $x^{1/n}$ grows faster).

Comment: No, it's **not** correct. You switched the functions...

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I should read the original post more carefully, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way see it: fix some $n>0$, and assume that there is a constant $C>0$ for which $$x^{1/n} \le C \log x,$$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Then plug in $y=x^{1/n}$ to obtain $$ y \le \tilde{C} \log y.$$